# Multiply matrix by vector rowwise (sweep)

Tags: matrix, vector, stan, elementwise-operations

Does STAN provide a method for multiplying each row of a matrix by a vector, elementwise? i.e. if I had a matrix:

```
[1,2,3,
 4,5,6]
```

and a vector:

```
[2,4,6]
```

the desired result would be a second matrix:

```
[2,8,18,
 8,15,36]
```

I'm sure I can do this as a for loop, but it seems like something I should be able to do without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stan has an [elementwise multiplication operator](https://mc-stan.org/docs/functions-reference/elementwise-functions.html): `.*`.  It applies only to objects of the same type (e.g., two vectors, or two matrices).  But we can use the `rep_matrix()` [broadcast function](https://mc-stan.org/docs/functions-reference/matrix-broadcast.html) to turn the vector into a matrix:

```
my_matrix .* rep_matrix(my_vector', rows(my_matrix))
```

If the vector is already a row vector in Stan, then the transposition is unnecessary:

```
my_matrix .* rep_matrix(my_row_vector, rows(my_matrix))
```